# Can I sharpen edges with fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

With fabric.js, is it possible to sharpen (drastically) the edges of objects added to the canvas?

Here's a zoomed-in picture of some small (5x5 pixels) squares I'm using, and they come out like the square on the right, but I need them to be the square on the left.

[image]

because I'm trying to take the produced image and turn the white background transparent and apply the resulting image on top of another image, and with those fuzzed borders, it comes out looking like absolute garbage once overlayed.  There isn't really a good solution involving changing the transparency threshold, because it ends up no longer being a perfect square if I drop it to get rid of the gray.

**After ensuring top/left are exact integers**

[image]

**After ctx.translate(0.50, 0.50)**

[image]

Comment: Make sure all your x, y, width & height values are exact integers.

Comment: Okay, that does seem to affect the shape, where now all of the squares look identical.  I guess it's feasible I could use the transparency method now, but it still doesn't seem to produce the square on the left.

Comment: Get a reference to the canvas context and do `context.translate(0.50,0.50)` Use only fills -- avoid strokes.

Comment: That definitely helps alot, still not quite all of the way though.  I'm not explicitly using strokes.  Do you know what the default does? Actually, the only properties I'm specifying for the rect are: top, left, width, height, and selectable.

Comment: That's about as good as it's going to get. If you allow dragging, be sure to listen to the drag events and `parseInt` those values too. FabricJS allows you to set either/both fill and stroke. The default is fill:black and stroke:null. Cheers!

Comment: To sharpen up edges of non transparent rendered objects you can render the object more than once. Not as easy in fabricJS but can be done by `instancing` the object and grouping two or more instances together. Because the copies are instances (just a reference) there is barely any memory or rendering overhead. This technique can be used to sharpen any edge (anti aliased boundary between 0 Alpha and 1 (255) Alpha) as long as the object does not contain semi transparent pixels. For Transparent objects you will need to do some masking and/or pixel manipulation.

Comment: @Blindman67: *Hint on how to implement your idea*: Since an html5 canvas can be an image source for a Fabric.Image, you can render the multi-drawn rectangle to an in-memory html5 canvas and then create a Fabric.Image from it. Both Fabric.Image & Fabric.Rect have most of the same properties and would likely be similarly useful. :-)

Comment: @markE Yes agree. There is an overhead associated with grouped objects, merging down will reduce the CPU/GPU load. This technique can give you very fine control over the antiAliasing strength, a little sharpness by just adding the original with globalAlpha = 0.25 or less or to Totally pixel art it render it many times. As canvas can render to self you double the effect every render call.